# Getting the contacts/ storing contacts to SIM card

Tags: gsm

I have the [GSM shield](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoGSMShield) and is there any ways to get the stored contacts on the SIM card? It seems that [the GSM library](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/GSM) does not support writing data onto/ reading data from the SIM card?

My aim is to store the SIM card's phone number and some variables onto the SIM card itself, such, I would not need to change the program from time to time.

All I need to do is enter all the variables in the SIM card via any mobile phone (perhaps by storing the variables as contacts, as phone book function should be very common on phones).

Answer (score 6):

What have you researched so far? Following the link you have given for the shield, about the third line of the description is a reference to the [AT Command Set](http://arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/Quectel_M10_AT_commands.pdf) used by the chip.

I just did a couple of quick searches through it and found:

> `2.2.4  ATD><n>` Originate phone call to number in memory
>
> `3.2.26 AT+CPBF` Find phone book entries
>
> `3.2.27 AT+CPBR` Read current phone book entries
>
> `3.2.28 AT+CPBS` Select phone book memory storage

probably a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Madivad for the AT command inspiration. I am not very familiar with GSM and Arduino. But anyway, the below worked for me.

Credits to @Madivad and [people from the arduino forum.](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=163155.0)

```
#include <GSM.h>
GSM gsmAccess(true);
int sizer = 200;
char myNumber[200];
int timeout = 5000; // in milli seconds

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  boolean notConnected = true;

  Serial.println("Connecting to the GSM network");

  while(notConnected){
    if(gsmAccess.begin() == GSM_READY) // Note: I do not require PIN #
      notConnected = false;
    else {
      Serial.println("Not connected, trying again");
      delay(1000);
    }
  }

  Serial.println("Connected");

  theGSM3ShieldV1ModemCore.println("AT+CPBS=\"SM\"");  
  int start1 = millis();   
  while((millis() - start1) < timeout){
    Serial.print(theGSM3ShieldV1ModemCore.theBuffer().read());
  }   
  Serial.print("Set to look at SIM card storage");

  // search for contact name "test"
  theGSM3ShieldV1ModemCore.println("AT+CPBF=\"test\"");  
  start1 = 0;
  start1 = millis();   
  while((millis() - start1) < timeout && !theGSM3ShieldV1ModemCore.theBuffer().extractSubstring(",\"", "\",", myNumber, sizer)){
    Serial.print(theGSM3ShieldV1ModemCore.theBuffer().read());
  }   
  Serial.print("Got contact number");

 // print out the phone of "test"
 Serial.println(myNumber);

}

void loop()
{

}
```