# How can I add phonebook entry to sim card using Arduino GSM shield?

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm

I am using Arduino GSM Module and Arduino UNO

[image]

I want my GSM module to be stand alone once I programmed it. It will store the phone number of the user if he sends a correct passcode. Since I want the data to available even after I power off my module. I need to store it to my sim. I don't want to use an SD card shield or store data to arduino's EEPROM.

I have read [Getting the contacts/ storing contacts to SIM card](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/1370/getting-the-contacts-storing-contacts-to-sim-card). The only clear reply is reading from the SIM.

Is it possible to add phonebook entry to SIM card?
Do you know a tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

.

Hope this helps.

Go check out (http://m2msupport.net/m2msupport/sim-phonebook-at-commands/) I use these commands on my AI Tinker A7 board for the Arduino.... 95% work perfectly...

Cheers,
Capt.K

ps. I made these numbers up but the formats are all correct.

```
//----------------------------------------------------------
//---Add Entry To PhoneBook:
//----------------------------------------------------------

AT+CPBW=1, "+61416199234",145, "Paul"    //-- add entry x1

OK

//----------------------------------------------------------
//--DELETE phonebook entry:
//----------------------------------------------------------

AT+CPBW=1  //-- delete entry x1

OK

//----------------------------------------------------------
//-- AT+CPBW=[<index>],<number> [ ,<type> [,<text>]]
//----------------------------------------------------------
//
//<index>   = Entry Number in SIM Memory
//<number>  = "The Phone number"
//<type>    = "The Phone Number" (TYPE ) ie. 129,161,145,177.. 
              //  129 – National number type
              //  161 – National number type
              //  145 – INternational number type
              //  177 – Network specific number
//<text>    = "Person Name" etc.

//----------------------------------------------------------
//  Add 4x new entries to the SIM card
//----------------------------------------------------------
AT+CPBW=1, "+61416199234",145, "Pops"
AT+CPBW=2, "+61420921234",145, "Mum"
AT+CPBW=3, "+61733728171",145, "Wendy"
AT+CPBW=4, "+61356821234",145, "Mr Smith" 

//NOTE:  In Australia (above examples) the actual phone numbers
//       above are of these types
//
// Int.Format    Aust. Dial Internal       Phone_Type
// ----------------------------------------------------------- 
// +61416199234  (0416) 199 234             Mobile/Cell
// +61420921234  (0420) 921 234             Mobile/Cell
// +61356821234  (03)   5682 1234           Landline/PSTN
```